# Is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse-function

Given $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, show that

$A=[-4,-1)\cup[0,6],$

$f(x)= \begin{cases}x+1 & \text { if } x \in[-4,-1)\text {, } \\ x & \text { if } x \in[0,6] ;\end{cases}$

is injective and find the image of $A$ under $f$. Is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

I know I’m missing something very obvious. I was able to show injectivity and $f(A)$, but is there a way to directly answer whether $f^{-1}$ is continuous based on that work?

Please provide a hint or key theorem, not the work itself.

Comment: Draw the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$, perhaps?

Comment: To determine whether the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is continuous, use the theorem that states that a function $f$ is continuous if and only if for any open set $U$ in the range of $f$, the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the domain of $f$.

So to determine whether $f^{-1}$ is continuous, you need to check whether $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$ for any open set $U$ in the range of $f$. You can use the fact that $f$ is injective to simplify the problem, since $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$ in $A$

Comment: Keep it simple. Draw the graphs and/or compare $f^{-1}(0)$ with $\lim_{y\to0^-}f^{-1}(y).$